# Como subtrair duas colunas resultantes de um pivot table

Tags: python

Eu fiz um pivot table e gostaria de fazer a subtração das colunas resultantes do pivotamento.

Base de teste

```
data ={'Codigo_Negociacao':["ELET3","ELET3","ELET3","ELET3","ELET3","ELET3","PETR4","PETR4","PETR4","PETR4","PETR4",
                            "PETR4"],
       'DT_FIM_EXERC':["2020-09-30","2020-09-30","2022-03-31","2022-03-31","2022-06-30","2022-06-30","2020-09-30",
                       "2020-09-30","2022-03-31","2022-03-31","2022-06-30","2022-06-30"],
       'CD_CONTA':["3.01","3.02","3.01","3.02","3.01","3.02","3.01","3.02","3.01","3.02","3.01","3.02"],
       'DS_CONTA':["Receita","Despesa","Receita","Despesa","Receita","Despesa","Receita","Despesa","Receita","Despesa",
                   "Receita","Despesa"],
       'VL_CONTA':["2000","1000","1500","1000","3000","2000","10000","7000","10000","5000","15000","3000"]
       }

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Cria lista de códigos

```
l_cad= df['Codigo_Negociacao'].tolist()
```

função que remove valores duplicados da lista

```
def remove repetidos(lista):
    l=[]
    for i in lista:
        if i not in l:
            l.append(i)
    return l

l_cad=remove repetidos(l_cad)
```

Fiz o pivot table

```
for ativo in l_cad:
    dre_base = df[df.Codigo_Negociacao== ativo].pivot_table(index=['CD_CONTA','DS_CONTA'],columns=['DT_FIM_EXERC'],values='VL_CONTA')
```

Os valores da coluna 'DT_FIM_EXERC' se tornarão as colunas resultantes da pivotamento.
Eu gostaria de fazer uma subtração entre duas colunas.
Eu tentei transformar o pivot table em DataFrame

```
dre_base.columns.name = None
dre_base.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Tentei fazer a subtração das colunas resultantes

```
y = 2022

dre_base[f'{y-1}-09-30'] = dre_base[f'{y-1}-09-30']-dre_base[f'{y}-06-30']
```

Mas isto resultou no seguinte erro

```
raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: '2021-09-30'
```

Comment: Coloque dados de teste para as pessoas conseguirem reproduzir o erro.

Comment: Comentário 1: Você não precisa de uma função para pegar os únicos. Basta usar `l_cad = df['Codigo_Negociacao'].unique()`. Comentário 2: o erro se dá, pois não existe coluna com data de `2021-09-30` (pelo menos no seu exemplo). Tem certeza que seria esta conta? Tente usar as datas do exemplo para verificar o resultado.

Comment: @PauloMarques obrigado pelo aviso. Ajustei as colunas e agora está ok.